# How to Use an Instance from One Class in Another Class: Greenfoot

Tags: java, methods, instance, greenfoot

I'm using Greenfoot at the moment, learning Java. I'm very noobish when it comes to static/non-static, and I'm iffy on instances also.

In Greenfoot, I have a world class, let's call it *World*. Now I have another class, named *Car* and one subclass, *Redcar*. Lastly, I have a *Button* class.

If you are familiar with Greenfoot, I've created an instance of Redcar, named *redcar* (just lowercase) and added it to *World* via addObject();

```
public World() { 

    super(1000, 200, 1); 

    Redcar redcar = new Redcar();
    Button button = new Button();

    addObject(redcar, 45, 45);
    addObject(button, 960, 175);
}
```

Within the *Car* class, which contains the following

```
public class Car extends Actor {

    int carSpeed = 0;

    public void drive() {
        carSpeed++;
        move(carSpeed);
    }
}
```

If called from *Redcar*, it will move the *Redcar* further each time drive is called. I want this to happen when *Button* is clicked on however. Within my *World* class, I want to set up something to the effect of this:

```
if (Greenfoot.mouseClicked(button)) {
    redcar.drive();
}
```

However, if that is put within the *World* constructor, it doesn't run when the Greenfoot project is run. I've tried putting it within a while loop, so that it continuously looks for the mouse click, but that doesn't work, in fact it actually crashes Greenfoot.

Sorry if this question is confusingly worded, I will touch it up if need be. Basically, my question is this. **How can I call a class's method to work on an instance, FROM a different class? For instance, the drive() method working on redcar (instance) from the button class**

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand your question you need to give visibility to the instances; something like this,

```
private Redcar redcar;                   // <-- if you want to access redcar in World.
public World() { 
  super(1000, 200, 1); 
  redcar = new Redcar();                    // <-- Use the redcar field
  Button button = new Button(this, redcar); // <-- if you want to access this World  
                                            // instance and redcar in Button.
  addObject(redcar, 45, 45);
  addObject(button, 960, 175);
}
```